# How do I compare x and y in F#?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I need help with the matching pattern that would compare 2 numbers. Something like that:

```
let test x y =
   match x with
   | y when x < y -> printfn "less than"
   | y when x > y -> printfn "greater than"
   | _ -> printfn "equal"
```

Somehow it falls to the "_" case when x is 0 and y is 200. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 17):

The problem with your code is that when you write:

```
match x with 
| y when x < y -> (...)
```

.. it means that you want to assign the value of `x` (the `<expr>` in `match <expr> with`) to a new variable named `y` (the `<pat>` in `| <pat> when ...`) and then compare this new `y` (which now contains the value of `x`) with the value of `x` - and so this will always return `false`. You can always rename the bound variable, so your code is the same as writing:

```
match x with 
| newY when x < newY -> (...)
```

Now you can see why this never matches - because you are just comparing `x` with itself!

Pattern matching is especially useful if you have inputs of some more complicated structure - like tuples or discriminated unions, lists, arrays, option types etc. But if you simply want to compare numbers, it is much easier to just use `if`:

```
let test x y =
  if x < y then printfn "less than"
  elif x > y then printfn "greater than"
  else printfn "equal"
```

In your `match`, you do not really need to bind any variables - but the solution by John demonstrates how you can make that work - it simply says, take variables `x` and `y` and assign them to new variables `x` and `y` (which just have the same name).

Answer (score 16):

A better version would be to pattern match on both numbers like so

```
let test x y =
   match (x,y) with
   | (x,y) when x < y -> printfn "less than"
   | (x,y) when x > y -> printfn "greater than"
   | _ -> printfn "equal"
```

Answer (score 7):

If you consult with [Pattern Matching (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx) upon what type of pattern matching you use, then it would be so-called *variable pattern*, where new variable `y` within the match cases will be assigned the value of match expression `x`. As this `y` variable inside `match` statement shadows the original function parameter `y`, in the first and the second cases `y` would be simply getting value of `x`, hence `when` guards both fail. Then, the third catch-all match case `_` kicks in, so you get "equal" return, as observed.

You can better see what happens if you explore the following snippet:

```
let f x y =
    match x with
    | y -> y
```

and try it with something like `f arg1 arg2`; `f` will be always returning `arg1` regardless of `arg2` value.

You may express your original intent still using matching with *constant pattern* by moving argument comparison into `match` expression:

```
let test x y =
    match sign (Operators.compare x y) with
    | 1 -> "greater than"
    | -1 -> "less then"
    | _ -> "equal"
```

Comment: Interesting approach Gene.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to John Palmer's answer.  I think writing it like this will improve your understanding of what is happening:

```
let test x y = 
    match (x,y) with
    | (a,b) when a < b -> printfn "less than"
    | (a,b) when a > b -> printfn "greater than"
    | _ -> printfn "equal"
```

In plain terms, when you use a `Match` statement, the terms in the pattern (i.e. the part before the `->`) declare new identifiers.  When you re-use `y` in your pattern, you are hiding the previous identifier `y` and creating a new one which has the same value as the thing on which you are matching, in this case the identifier `x`.  In other words, you are always comparing the value of `x` to itself.  As others have noted, this is probably best done with an `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Pattern  matching is a poor choice for that, use `if` instead:

```
if x < y then
  printfn "less than"
elif x > y then
  printfn "greater than"
else
  printf "equal"
```

Answer (score 0):

replace *match **x** with* to *match **y** with*

```
let test x y =
       match y with
       | y when x < y -> printfn "less than"
       | y when x > y -> printfn "greater than"
       | _ -> printfn "equal"
```